# Python2 json: load using strings instead of unicode

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

I have a json string that I want to parse into a dictionary using the built in `json` module.  I'm able to do this using `loads()`, as follows:

```
>>> j = '''{
...   "first": 1,
...   "second": "two",
...   "third": {
...     "first": "one",
...     "second": null
...   }
... }'''
>>> d = json.loads(j)
>>> pprint(d)
{u'first': 1,
 u'second': u'two',
 u'third': {u'first': u'one',
            u'second': None}}
```

The issue is everything loads as a `unicode`.  Is there a way to force python to load everything as a `string` instead?  Alternatively, is there a simple way to do a deep convert once the `dict` is created.

NOTE: Because I know people will ask, it is safe to assume that the keys and values I get will contain only ASCII characters and symbols, so I will not have a problem with special characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could supply an `object_hook` or `object_pairs_hook` parameter to [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads).

```
from pprint import pprint
import json

def str_hook(obj):
    return {k.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(k,unicode) else k :
            v.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(v, unicode) else v
            for k,v in obj}

j = '''{
  "first": 1,
  "second": "two",
  "third": {
    "first": "one",
    "second": null
  }
}'''
d = json.loads(j, object_pairs_hook=str_hook)
pprint(d)
```